# let the user choose role upon registration

Tags: users

I'd like to let the front-end user to choose user role upon registration.

When the register form submit, I'd like it to redirect to the respective profile page concerning with their chosen role.

I use [profile2](http://drupal.org/project/profile2) module and [profile2 registration path](http://drupal.org/project/profile2_regpath) module.

Is there any existing module for that ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you love custom coding and if you already have a custom module, I would recommend to do this with a custom module rather than using [Profile 2](http://drupal.org/project/profile2) and other related modules. I personally prefer to write custom modules because it will let you get exactly what you are looking for. 
But you still need to use [Auto Assign Role](http://drupal.org/project/autoassignrole) module to let user choose a user role on registration.

My solution is to show/hide the respective profile fields upon user role selection on the registration form. It would not redirect to the respective profile page.
You can create profile fields at **admin/config/people/accounts/fields** and you can export them to the registration form, but they cannot be created by role. What you would need to do is to show/hide each field by role from [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) and use [#ajax](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#ajax) attribute.

Here is an code snippet for this purpose. I did not test the code. Just for example.

```
function yourmodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

    if($form_id == 'user_register_form' || $form_id == 'user_profile_form'){

        $form['autoassignrole_user']['user_roles']['#ajax'] = array(
          // #ajax has two required keys: callback and wrapper.
          // 'callback' is a function that will be called when this element changes.
          'callback' => 'ajax_form_alter',
          // 'wrapper' is the HTML id of the page element that will be replaced.
          'wrapper' => 'replace_field_div',
          // Don't show any throbber...
          'progress' => array('type' => 'none'),              
         );

        # This profile field will be shown or hidden when the respective "user_roles" is selected
        $form['field_first_name']['und'][0]['value']['#type']       = 'hidden';
        $form['field_first_name']['und'][0]['value']['#required']   = FALSE;
        $form['field_first_name']['und'][0]['value']['#type']       = 'hidden';
        $form['field_first_name']['und'][0]['value']['#prefix']     = '<div id="replace_field_div">';
        $form['field_first_name']['und'][0]['value']['#suffix']     = '</div>';

        // An AJAX request calls the form builder function for every change.
        // We can change how we build the form based on $form_state.        
        if(isset($form_state['values']['autoassignrole_user']['user_roles']) && $form_state['values']['autoassignrole_user']['user_roles'] == {rid_here}){
            # when the respective user roles is selected, show this field and set required.
            $form['field_first_name']['und'][0]['value']['#type']       = 'textfield';
            $form['field_first_name']['und'][0]['value']['#required']   = TRUE;   
        }else{ 
            # when the respective user roles, hide this field and remove required.
            $form['field_first_name']['und'][0]['value']['#type']       = 'hidden';
            $form['field_first_name']['und'][0]['value']['#required']   = FALSE;           
        }
    }
}
/**
 * Callback for user_roles
 *
 * On an ajax submit, the form builder function is called again, then the $form
 * and $form_state are passed to this callback function so it can select which
 * portion of the form to send on to the client.
 *
 * @return renderable array (the textfield element)
 */     
function ajax_form_alter($form, $form_state){
    return $form['field_first_name']; 
}
```

You may notice that you have to use `['und'][0]['value']` for the profile field to tweak its attributes. If you are not sure about this, you can print $form for debugging purpose:

```
dpm($form); // if Devel module is enabled
echo '<pre>'; print_r($form); echo '</pre>'; // if you don't have Devel module
```

If there is another better solution, please post it and it will be appreciated.

Comment: I adopt your solution as it suits my needs.  Thanks for the help.  However, I need to change a little.   For one thing, change `$form_state['values']['autoassignrole_user']['user_roles']` to `$form_state['values']['user_roles']`.  And instead of using fixed {rid_here}, I use user_role_load_by_name().

Answer (score 2):

checkout the [Auto Assign Role](http://drupal.org/project/autoassignrole).

> The Auto Assign Role serves three primary purposes. The first is to
>   provide an automatic assignment of roles when a new account is
>   created. The second is to allow the end user the option of choosing
>   their own role or roles when they create their account. The third is
>   to provide paths that will trigger a specific role when an account is
>   created. The administrator has full control over these functions and
>   can have them working together or independently of each other.