# creating users form in drupal 7

Tags: 7, forms, users

What is the easiest way to prepare separate admin panels for creating users of different roles/profiles e.g. 'add editor', 'add client', 'add subscriber' etc. that will have separate set of fields?

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with [drupal module development](http://drupal.org/developing/modules), I would recommend to write custom code. You may have 3 user roles - editor, client and subscriber. You can create user fields at **admin/config/people/accounts/fields**, but you cannot have separate set of fields by role. You can manage (hide/show) those fields upon user role selection from your custom module.

Please check [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/49889/let-the-user-choose-role-upon-registration/50079#50079).