# How to let a user choose a role after their very first login?

Tags: users

I want to let users to select their role. There are 4 available roles (created by me as an admin) and the selection should be done **after** first login, so not on the registration form.

Can anyone help me to resolve this problem?

Note: the question [let the user choose role upon registration](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/49889/) is not exactly the same as my question here: that one contains "**... with their chosen role ...**", which is clearly something they entered on the registration form.

Comment: Duplicate of http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/49889/let-the-user-choose-role-upon-registration?

Comment: Why don't you let them to select their role on registration instead of logging in?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but you can try somthing lke this: create form with Form API, on submission change value of Role array in user object.
Example:

```
function MENUCALLBACKNAME($form, &$form_state, $user) {
 $form = array();
 $form['role'] = array(
  '#title' => t('select role'),
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#options' => //Array of your roles like array(id_of_role => t('Name of Role'), ...)
 );

 $form['uid'] = array(
  '#type' => 'value',
  '#value' => $user->uid,
 );

 $form['submit'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => t('Choose'),
 );

 return $form;
}

function MENUCALLBACKNAME_submit($form, &$form_state) {
 $uid = $form_state['values']['uid'];
 $role = $form_state['values']['role'];

 $account = user_load($uid);

 $account->roles = $role;
 user_save($account);
 $form_state['redirect'] = 'SOME PATH';
}
```

Comment: I am using Profile 2 module, can You suggest me another solution ( module solution is preferable)

Comment: for me it is more comfortable to write code then installing contrib modules and configure them and so on :) I do not know how Profile2 module works but role which is assined to user is located in user object. Proile2 module does not matter here. Just create simple module, create hook_menu, alter registration form submit and after registration redirect user to that page which you created with hook_menu. it's done:)... I do not know there is any contrib module which can do this functionality.